# Elasticsearch: Get Parent and Child in same query with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am doing a Search Engine with ES. I have the Type "webContent" and two subtypes, "htmlDocuments", "textDocuments". **webContent** has fields like title, date_of_creation, etc. **htmlDocuments** and **textDocuments** types have fields like contenttext, url, etc. The parent and child id are the same.

When I search in NEST, I would like to have the parent and child. Every  child(htmlDocuments or textDocuments) has a parent of type Webcontent. And also, every WebContent has just one child of type htmlDocuments or textDocuments. For example, I want to search a Text document where Title contains the word "university":So, my query is:

```
var child = client.Search<textDocuments>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .HasParent<webContent>(c => c
                .Query(cq => cq.MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m.Field(p => p.title).Query("university"))))
            ));
```

So, this return textDocuments. Is it possible to return both parents and childs? Or a way to get the parent without do another query? I want to avoid do two queries like I am doing now:

```
var hits = resul.Hits.ToList();
// for i = 0 until hits.count:
var parent = client.Search<webContent>(b => b
                .Query(q => q
                  .Term(tx => tx.id, child.hits[i].Parent)));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider flattening parent/child into one document, given each parent has only one child?

Comment: Yes, I thought it, but this is the structure that I'm using now with another search engine with a SQL database.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I can't seem to find an example.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I solved the problem.  I first created an index with a parent/child mapping like this:

```
        var request = new CreateIndexRequest("things");
        request.Mappings = new Mappings();
        request.Mappings.Add("parent", new TypeMapping());
        request.Mappings.Add("child", new TypeMapping { ParentField = new ParentField { Type = "parent" } });
        _client.CreateIndex(request);
```

Then to include parent documents with children I performed the query like this:

```
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("things", "child")
        {
            From = 0,
            Size = 10,
            Query = new HasParentQuery
            {
                Type = "parent",
                InnerHits = new InnerHits(),
                Query = new MatchAllQuery()
            }
        };

        var response = _client.Search<Child>(request);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include Child and Parent poco classes? I cant figure out if parent should have a child property or not